# C# - Get processes sorted by processor load usage

Tags: c#, windows, optimization, process

What's the lighest way to get a running processes list sorted by processor load? (kind of same as task manager but only sorted by processor usage load)
Lighest is the key word, because i want to make an updated and refreshed list every 2 seconds or something like that.

EDIT : using windows 7

Comment: At bare minimum you need to tell us what OS you are using.

Comment: win7, sorry about the missing info

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading into the Process class 
- System.Diagnostics.Process

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)
I would recommend looking at the [GetProcesses()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx) method within here.

Comment: thanks for yuor answer, but i already read all of that, and sadly, it doesn't tell me how to get them sorted by processor usage load. Could you maybe help me with that?